# I want to insert match string at the beginning of each line after match string in Windows

Tags: string, insert, match

I want to insert match string at the beginning of
each line after match string in Windows

I have large text file which i have to filter

**original file:-**

raj blue MatchString1

blue green yellow

bird cat dog

vellow yes MatchString2

reg edit last

arrow edit blue

**Target file:-**

raj blue matchString1

MatchString1 blue green yellow

MatchString1 bird cat dog

MatchString1 vellow yes matchString2

MatchString2 reg edit last

MatchString2 arrow edit blue

Comment: Consider adding which technology/tool/language you want to code e.g. Java etc. You need to: 1. initialize a flag to false, 2. open original file in read mode & new file in write mode. 03. read original file line by line. 4. if flag =true, write match+current line to new file else write current line to new file 5. when you get match in any line, set flag to true

Comment: i want to achieve result in windows  dos or  powershell command

Comment: you should try with above steps in any scripting language that you work on. Asking for code is not correct. Try something & if you face any issue, put your code with logs so that people can help.